# How Android Async Task Works with UrlConnection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new with the android. I am developing an app that will load content from target url in file. If the url didn't work, it will contact our server to request the correct url. If still fail, then it will ask the url from user input dialog. And it will try to initialize again.  I have code like this:

```
    if (initialize(target)!=true) {
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonParam.put("sns", getSerial(PREF_NAME));
            jsonParam.put("code", pwd);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        target = getContent(samURL + "/sam_ip", jsonParam);
        if (initialize(target)!=true) {
            askIpUserDialog();
        }
    }
```

and the initialize() as follow

```
private boolean initialize(String url) {
    Boolean success = false;
    if ((!url.trim().startsWith("http://")) && (!url.trim().startsWith("https://"))) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    if (url.endsWith("/")) {
        url = url.substring(0,url.length()-1);
    }
    String sUrl = url + "/android_view";

    URL pUrl;
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    try {
        DataOutputStream printout;
        DataInputStream input;
        pUrl = new URL (sUrl);
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) pUrl.openConnection();
        urlConn.setDoInput (true);
        urlConn.setDoOutput (true);
        urlConn.setUseCaches (false);
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        urlConn.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");
        urlConn.connect();

        //Create JSONObject here
        JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
        jsonParam.put("snc", serialClient);
        jsonParam.put("code", pwd);

        printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream());
        String str = jsonParam.toString();
        byte[] data = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        printout.write(data);
        printout.flush();
        printout.close ();

        int HttpResult = urlConn.getResponseCode();
        if(HttpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            success = true;
            WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
            view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
            view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            view.loadUrl(sUrl);
        }else{
            success = false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        if(urlConn!=null)
            urlConn.disconnect();
    }
    return success;
}
```

I just know that in android, url connection should run in separate thread. That's why I got the following error:

```
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork
```

My question is, how do I use AsyncTask to avoid the error? 
I saw there is doInBackground() which I can put the initialize() function there.
I saw also there is onPostExecute() event which I can check the result from the doInBackground(), but I don't understand yet how do I retrieve the return of initialize() which placed inside doInBackground()?

Bonus question, later I'd like to place all this job inside an intentservice. Do I need to stil use the asynctask? Does intentservice itself is an asynctask?

Comment: AsyncTask is fine. Where are you using it ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I placed the code inside onCreate in MainActivity. I don't know how to pass the result of the initialize (a boolean value) to the onPostExecute.

Comment: which is not an AsyncTask.

Comment: @Blackbelt yes, that's why I'd like to convert it to use AsyncTask instead. But I don't know which best approach to implement it.

Comment: you can pass parameters to asynctask as below `private class Xay extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

  @Override
  protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }
  
 }`

Comment: and when you call asynctask `new new Xay().execute(parameterdata);`

Comment: @KaranMer Let say I put initialize(target) which will return boolean value inside doInBackground. How do I access the return boolean value in onPostExecute()?

Comment: thats what `Result` is for

Comment: make your async task as follow `yourclass extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Boolean>`

Comment: you need to mind it will use `Boolean` not `boolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try some thing like this and also u can use a different thread

```
   final Handler h = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final File file  = new File(path);
            Log.i("path",path);
            downloadFile(url[j], file);
            h.post(new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {

                txt.setText(""+jp);
                jp++;

                }

            });
            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();

}

private static void downloadFile(String url, File outputFile) {
      try {
          URL u = new URL(url);
          URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
          int contentLength = conn.getContentLength();
          Log.i("len","" + contentLength);
          Log.i("url1","Streaming from "+url+ "...."); 
          DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(u.openStream());

            byte[] buffer = new byte[contentLength];
            stream.readFully(buffer);
            stream.close();

            DataOutputStream fos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
      } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.v("FileError" , e.toString());
          return; // swallow a 404
      } catch (IOException e) {
          Log.v("FileError" , e.toString());
          return; // swallow a 404
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          Log.v("FileError" , e.toString());
          return; // swallow a 404
      }
    }
```

and also you cant access ui elements on different thread you have to use handler or run on ui thread.

```
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    try{   
        this.pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading..", "Please Wait...", true, false);
        new AsyncAction().execute();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected Void doInBackground(String... args) { 
          //do your stuff here        }
}
```

}

Comment: Can I do this: protected Void doInBackground(String... args) { if (initialize(target)!=true) { new AsyncAction().execute(otherTarget); } }

Comment: I follow your snippet by using the asynctask, and it works ..! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Network traffic (and all other logic which takes some time to process) should always be handled by a background thread and never on the Main thread.

Use an ASyncTask to execute the logic.

```
private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       // perform your network logic here
        return "YourResult";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Update your screen with the results.
    }
}
```

Call the ASyncTask in your code:

```
new YourTask().execute("");
```